# Setting fields on and object referenced by the 'with' statement

Tags: javascript, with-statement

In JavaScript, I simulate classes like this:

```
function MyClass() {} // Constructor

MyClass.prototype.myField = "foo";
```

I thought I'd make the code more readable and save keystrokes by using the `with` keyword:

```
function MyClass() {} // Constructor

with (MyClass.prototype)
{
    myField = "foo";

    myOtherField = "bar";

    myMethod = // etc
}
```

But if I then create an instance and try to access any of those fields, they're `undefined`. However, if I do `with (MyClass.prototype)` and then try to read values from it, that works - it's only when I try to change them or create new fields that it fails. I'm assuming this is because `with (myObject)` scopes you to a clone of myObject, not an actual reference to the original instance.

So, is there any way to get around this? Any way to produce the results I want, with or with out `with`? Or am I doomed to writing out `MyClass.prototype` over and over again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"if I then create an instance and try to access any of those fields, they're `undefined`"*

You can't create new fields that way.

> *"if I do `with (MyClass.prototype)` and then try to read values from it, that works"*

This is because you can read and update existing fields.

> *"I'm assuming this is because `with (myObject)` scopes you to a clone of `myObject`, not an actual reference to the original instance. "*

No, it's an actual reference to the object.

---

This sort of confusion is part of the reason why people avoid `with`.

---

> "*So, is there any way to get around this? Any way to produce the results I want, with or with out with? Or am I doomed to writing out MyClass.prototype over and over again?"*

Just use a variable.

```
var p = MyClass.prototype;

p.myField = "foo";
p.myOtherField = "bar";
p.myMethod = "etc";
```

You can also overwrite the existing prototype object, allowing object literal notation...

```
function MyClass() {}

MyClass.prototype = {
    myField: "foo",
    myOtherField: "bar",
    myMethod: "etc"
};
```

You can also add a `constructor: MyClass` if you want that.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this article](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/) which explains why you shouldn't use the with statement - the myField, myOtherField and myMethod variables will be created as global variables in your code because they don't already exist as properties of the prototype object.